# I keep getting a BSOD error or for heap corruption

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod

[This is the event ID for what’s causing my BSOD errors, BSOD code is KERNEL_MODE_HEAP_CORRUPTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edpLa.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to include the error message as text

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].

Comment: Does this help:   https://www.stellarinfo.com/article/fix-kernel-mode-heap-corruption-bsod.php#:~:text=The%20KERNEL_MODE_HEAP_CORRUPTION%20BSOD%20error%20occurs,increasing%20the%20page%20file%20size.     ... Article suggest RAM error